# How to create Glance similar to the one in the BBC news app?

Tags: ios, watchkit, user-experience, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I am studying the **BBC news** [App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bbc-news/id377382255?mt=8) for **Apple watch**. Here is how the glance looks like:

[image]

However, when I look into the **storyboard** for the Glance controller I can see **only these options available** for the **top part of the glance**:

[image]

The one that looks more similar to the BBC news app is the following option:

[image]

I thought that they could be changing the size of the group on the left and adding an image representing a red bar. However, when I tried to replicate this, I wasn't able to resize the group.

**How do you think they achieved this?**

Comment: I think they used the one in the column 1, row 4 where a single Label is above  the Group.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to pull this off is to choose the first arrangement. Within the single group, you would:

- Add a new group with a fixed width and a relative height of 1. Set its background color to red.
- After the new group, add a multi-line label (lines = 0) so that the title flows across multiple lines.

Update: Just tried this technique in Xcode, and with a few spacing tweaks, I was able to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. For the left side bar, I would use the **Separator**. What do you think, Mike?

Comment: `WKInterfaceSeparator` is horizontal only, so it wouldn't work in this situation. The common technique is to use a group with a background color. You can also set the corner radius to "round" the edges, though it doesn't appear that the BBC app does this.

Comment: You are right. But, I can put it to vertical. I just tried it.

Comment: But **separator** might be too small in some cases? You're welcome. lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should understand how we layout the watch app compared to the normal iPhone app. The layout in watch app is just like **Android**. You have to specify orientation of UI elements instead of dragging around freely. For example, the default **Glance** has two groups and their orientation is horizontal.

For your question, I think you can achieve it using the default template. You can drag the **Separator** to be the left side bar and change it to the red color. Then, drag the **Label** to fit the rest the space.